# Solidworks Extrude Base/Boss - Base Extrude Doesn't Seem to Exist Anymore?

Tags: cad, solidworks

I've started using SolidWorks migrating from other software, Creo Parametric (formerly Pro/E) and the Base/Boss terminology confused me. After significant research, I've found that a "base feature" represents the starting feature and a "boss feature" represents any features built off of that - http://help.solidworks.com/2020/english/solidworks/acadhelp/c_feature_based_models.htm.

However, through using SolidWorks 2020, and from many different tutorials, I have never been able to make the first feature a base feature, e.g. "**Base**-Extrude1", but rather it alway shows as a boss feature, e.g. "**Boss**-Extrude1". Has the "Extrude Base" been deprecated from SolidWorks and Extrudes are always boss extrudes now or am I just doing it wrong? Are there any differences in the Property Manager for base features vs boss features?

[image: Example of Simple Extrude that shows as Boss-Extrude1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference at all - an extrude is an extrude is an extrude (unless it's a cut)

SolidWorks differs from some other CAD in that Boss and Cut are separate tools - others have just one extrude tool with a Boolean toggle in the feature manager

You can (and should for your own sanity) rename features in the tree to better represent what they are to you. Call it Base if that helps you!